# How will a user set up an environment variable accessible from a subshell?

Tags: linux, unix

```
Set -x command
set command
By direct assignment
export command
```

I tried figuring out for its answer but could not find a perfect answer.
This question might be silly but I really need to know it answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which shell, so I have assumed 'bash':

The answer is d) export command

example script test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export A=xxx
B=yyy
./test2.sh
```

and another script test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "A=$A"
echo "B=$B"
```

then:

```
$>   ./test1.sh
```

will print:

```
A=xxx
B=
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the syntax:

```
VAR=value command
```

exports *VAR* to *command* and executes *command*. Sometimes this way is more clear than other.